# Error while running tests on a single Go directory file

Tags: go, testing, runtime-error, tdd

I'm following a tutorial on Go, and I have the actual file tree:

```
.
├── arrays
├── concurrency
├── di
├── hello-world
├── integers
├── iteration
├── maps
├── mocking
├── pointers
├── racer
└── structs
```

If I run the tests in all of the folders files, they work, except for the folder called **racer**,
where running the tests gives me the following error:

```
# runtime/cgo
cgo: exec /missing-cc: fork/exec /missing-cc: no such file or directory
FAIL    github.com/Gabriel2233/go-with-tests/racer [build failed]
```

Is it related to something I'm doing in the files? This is the test file

```golang
package racer

import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func TestRacer(t *testing.T) {
    slowServer := makeDelayedServer(20 * time.Millisecond)
    fastServer := makeDelayedServer(0 * time.Millisecond)

    defer slowServer.Close()
    defer fastServer.Close()

    slowURL := slowServer.URL
    fastURL := fastServer.URL

    want := fastURL
    got := Racer(slowURL, fastURL)

    if got != want {
        t.Errorf("got %q, want %q", got, want)
    }

    t.Run("returns error if race takes more than 10s", func(t *testing.T) {
        serverA := makeDelayedServer(time.Second * 11)
        serverB := makeDelayedServer(time.Second * 12)

        defer serverA.Close()
        defer serverB.Close()

        _, err := Racer(serverA.URL, serverB.URL)

        if err == nil {
            t.Error("expected an error but didn't get one")
        }
    })
}

func makeDelayedServer(delay time.Duration) *httptest.Server {
    handler := http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        time.Sleep(delay * time.Millisecond)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    })
    server := httptest.NewServer(handler)

    return server
}
```

This is the racer.go file

```golang
package racer

import (
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func Racer(a, b string) (winner string) {
    select {
    case <-ping(a):
        return a
    case <-ping(b):
        return b
    }
}

func ping(url string) chan struct{} {
    ch := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        http.Get(url)
        close(ch)
    }()

    return ch
}

func measureResponseTime(url string) time.Duration {
    start := time.Now()
    http.Get(url)
    return time.Since(start)
}
```

I created a second directory in my tree, and I realized that both of the folders that use the go package **httptest** give me the same error mentioned above in the problem

Comment: What are the other files in the `racer` directory? I mean those without the `.go` extension.

Comment: The error message is about cgo (way to write Go code that calls into C code) being unable to find the C compiler. The files you show above don't appear to use cgo, so I assume some dependency or file not shown is using it. It would say `import "C"` at the top of the file.

Comment: There are only two files in the directory: ```racer.go``` and ```racer_test.go```

Comment: Where do I need to import "C" ? I tried on both of the files and got another runtime error

Answer (score 1):

I think, from the name of the test directory, that it uses the race detector, and the race detector depends on cgo. I just verified this for myself, if you make a small program (I called mine `ra.go`) that looks like:

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

var x string

//go:noinline
func check() {
    if x != "Hello world!" {
        fmt.Printf("FAIL, wanted 'Hello world!' but got '%s'\n", x)
    }
}

func main() {
    x = "Not Hello World, haha"
    check()
}
```

If you build it `go build ra.go` that should work fine, but if you turn on the race detector, `go build -race ra.go` I suspect you will see the same error message.  Exactly how to fix it depends on your OS; on macOS (where I am testing all this as I go) you would need to install [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) and its command-line tools.  Linux has a more complicated answer, and Windows I just don't know (I should, but I don't).

To see what's going on behind the curtain (this might be TMI), try the following:

```
go clean -cache
go build -x -race ra.go >& race.log
go build -x ra.go >& plain.log
```

and then examine those two log files.  On macOS `race.log` will contain things like

```
clang -fno-caret-diagnostics -c -x c - -o /dev/null || true
```

and later (if it is successful)

```
TERM='dumb' clang -I /Users/drchase/work/go-1.15/src/runtime/cgo -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK/b034=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common -I ./ -g -O2 -Wno-nullability-completeness -Wall -Werror -o ./_x001.o -c _cgo_export.c
```